# How to use asyncio with pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-asyncio

I have a dataframe with shape as (2000,3). One of the columns has the url. I need to call the url mentioned in each column, get the value and update in another columns. Sample Below

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | url to be called |
| A2 | B2 | url to be called |

Say, Column C has url. and the output of api response has to be updated in Column B. Any way to do this asynchronously.

I tried with multiprocessing pool but it takes time to process 2000 rows. Expecting a better way